# How to read an array/data from other html file in jQuery and create dynamic table (PLC webserver)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, plc

I`m working with PLC controllers. I have created a webserver on a PLC and I want to show data block in html. I already know that I must write:

```
 :="webdata".counter[0]:
```

But I have 2 problems.
1) I want to load this data in table and here is a problem. When i try:

```
for(var r = 0; r < 3; r++) {  
     document.write(":=\"webdata\".test[" + r + "]:")
};
```

There is nothing in page (in PLC i have an array of 55). So I`ve created an array and table

```
var edr = [
    {
        "Pallet": ":="webdata".test[0]:",
        "code": "8501H984P",
        "Cycles": ":="pallet_data".cycles[0]:"
    },
    {
        "Pallet": ":="webdata".test[1]:",
        "code": "8501H984P",
        "Cycles": ":="pallet_data".cycles[1]:"
    }
]
```

```
        var col = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < edr.length; i++) {
            for (var key in edr[i]) {
                if (col.indexOf(key) === -1) {
                    col.push(key);
                }
            }
        }  
        var table = document.createElement("table");
        var tr = table.insertRow(-1);                   // TABLE ROW.
        for (var i = 0; i < col.length; i++) {
            var th = document.createElement("th");      // TABLE HEADER.
            th.innerHTML = col[i];
            tr.appendChild(th);
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < edr.length; i++) {
            tr = table.insertRow(-1);
            for (var j = 0; j < col.length; j++) {
                var tabCell = tr.insertCell(-1);
                tabCell.innerHTML = edr[i][col[j] ];
            }
        }
        var divContainer = document.getElementById("showData");
        divContainer.innerHTML = "";
        divContainer.appendChild(table);
```

And this works but I have to type whole array. Is there a solution of this?

2) Also to update data I use jQuery

```
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
            setInterval(function() {
                $.get("IO.html", function(result){
                    $('#counter').text(result.trim());
                });
            },3000);
        });
```

but I have to create a html file with `:="webdata".test[0]:` inside. I cannot find a solution to extract only a part of html document.

I will be grateful for your help :)